# SpriteKit Liquid (water)

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, liquid

How can I get a small amount of liquid in my spriteKit application?

I want that liquid in a container, it will be sealed inside but I want it to be able to move around.

Is there a better way to implement this? Maybe an option without SpriteKit?

EDIT:
I was able to simulate water using this tutorial: 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/85515/liquidfun-tutorial-1

and this sample project I found:
https://github.com/safx/liquidfun-ios-sample

BUT it requires me to run 2 physics worlds (1 for box2D and 1 with spriteKit). Does anyone know how I can get my particles from box2D into spriteKit? I imagine this should be doable since spriteKit runs on box2D as well right?

Comment: What do you mean is there a better way to implement this?  What are you comparing to?  What are you trying to make the liquid look like?  I personally would have a number of small circles with small physics bodies inside the container with a physics body.  The small circles could be colored blue (or whatever color the liquid is).  However, it will be slightly lumpy...

Comment: No, that is way too demanding for sprite kit and would freeze after 100 circles I believe

Comment: Okay, would something like [LiquidKit](https://github.com/kevinhartman/LiquidKit) work for you?  I haven't used it before, but it seems interesting.

Answer (score 5):

I can suggest you **"LiquidFun"**. Its very easy to Install and it is fun to play around with it. 
You can build Games like "Where's my Water?"... and others!

Here is a link to a tutorial from RayWenderlich: [Click Me](http://www.raywenderlich.com/85515/liquidfun-tutorial-1)

I hope that this was helpful!

> // But Note that this Version of LiquidFun is only for XCode 6.3

Greetings!

Comment: I need it to run on xCode 7. Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: @NickProvost Did you try it with Xcode 7? It should work fine. The Swift code will be different, but the actual wrapper around LiquidFun was written in Objective-C. That will still work fine. Your actual app code will be completely different than the app code in the tutorial anyway.

Comment: @BenKane I am working on it now. Right now I am trying to figure out the physics world issue. Since I already had one with sprite kit and the tutorial creates one to put the particles in but of a different type (b2world instead of SKPhysicsWorld)

Comment: @BenKane So it does work. Although it is a pain in the butt so far. It seems as if I have to use a physics world with box2d (for liquidfun) and my physics world with sprite kit. Does anyone know how I can implement it in my own physics world? Box2d is not as fun to use as sprite kit. 

Here is an amazing sample that helped me as well as the tutorial
https://github.com/safx/liquidfun-ios-sample

Comment: If you really need a true physics world I wouldn't suggest trying to make your own. It would be very complicated to get right. If you just need some stuff like velocity, acceleration, mass, other simple things, you can do it. You'd just make the calculations yourself.

Comment: @BenKane No, its a physics world with box2d created for liquidfun and one created for sprite kit. 

Liquidfun is not a good solution. All the physics bodies would have to be converted to a second physics world. Its not elegant and doesn't work as well.

Comment: @NickProvost were you able to make any progress? I am trying to do something similar

Comment: @OnlyCodeMatters No I have not but I still want to get this. Did you get anything?