# Generate body of water in top down Spritekit game

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm currently working on a top down sprite based game using swift and spritekit, and I'm trying to create a body of water.

I have tiles that transition into water, and some water sprites that i have layered underneath that are animating, but it looks cheap.

I'm wondering if there is a way to generate a body of water using particles or something? I'm fairly new to swift and iOS development in general and this is something i've never done, so i'm just not sure what is possible.

If anybody has any advice or could point me in the right direction that would be great! Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33153574/spritekit-liquid-water or this : https://github.com/kevinhartman/LiquidKit